# Sympy solve will not return an answer

Tags: python, performance, sympy, equation

I am trying to use sympy to solve an equation for a one dimensional steady state model of the solar wind. I have the code below

```
from sympy import Eq, var, solve
var('r',real=True)
eq = Eq((1./2.)*((CF**2)/(r))+CT*r**(gamma)+bm/(2.*muo) - CM)
a = solve(eq,r)
```

Where CF, CT, CM, gamma, muo, and bm are just real numbers. I am trying to solve the equation for r over a range of values for bm but it will not return any numbers. Upon running the block of code, my python notebook just displays that the code is running but doesnt return a value nor does it stop. Is there an alternative function or some sort of command I should be giving to sympy in order to make it work faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation involves the sum of two powers of r, including r**gamma. Unless gamma is a very small integer (between -4 and 4), there is no hope of solving this symbolically (which is what sympy is for).

To solve it numerically, you need scipy rather than sympy. For example:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
func = lambda r : (1./2.)*((CF**2)/(r))+CT*r**(gamma)+bm/(2.*muo) - CM
# assign some numeric values to CF, CT, gamma, bm, muo, CM
sol = fsolve(func, 1)   # 1 is the initial guess for the solver
```